# How to uninstall and install a app for every test in XCUITest (Xcode 11.7)

Tags: xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

In my present app, after user registers, we won't show the register screen again

Is there any way to uninstall and install the app or at-least to clear the app cache to get the register screen for every test.

I am using XCODE 11.7 and i am running the test in parallel.